# Apache htccess rewrite rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My site is built in Angularjs, I am trying to re direct my site to html static snapshots pages in a snapshot folder, I can mange to get google to re-direct to the snapshot folder and to the correct links inside the folder, but cant seem to get Facebook to work, any thoughts?

Here is my htaccess file below

```
RewriteEngine on

# RewriteRule for GOOGLE ROOT URL

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} upfrontbeats\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/index.html [L]

# RewriteRule for GOOGLE ROOT ALL OTHER URLS

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} Googlebot
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^_escaped_fragment_=/?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/%1? [NC,L]

# RewriteRule for FACEBOOK 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} facebookexternalhit/1.1 [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _escaped_fragment_=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /snapshots/$1? [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This is very unclear. Can you clarify what behaviour you want, and what you are seeing?

Comment: I want facebook share to be redirected to my snapshot folder with the generated snapshot for that url

Comment: Can you clarify what behaviour you are expecting *exactly* (like, URL so and so gets redirected to URL so and so) and what is happening instead? Are you seeing no redirection at all? A 404 error? Some other error?

Comment: when I use the facebook debug tool and re scrape it just picking up the original url and not with snapshot redirect, Im getting a response code 200 and Fetched URL is the same as entered. So I am assuming that my rewrite rule is not working..

Comment: Please do not add details here in comments. There is an "edit" button below your question. _Use it ..._ Revise your question so that it gets more clear. Try to think from our perspective. We know nothing about your site, what you want, what you have. So you need to tell us. You want us to understand. So it is your task to make it easy for us to understand...